# Move a JFrame without the windows titlebar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I created my first app with JFrame. I set setUndecored to true and have no idea how to move the application with the mouse, ideas?
This's my code

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read (new URL("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/oBfgN7VB2KJ9FwpXqBLhEJqLxlNTxDLdEEnbKOKiXIl0gP2-Ccw2VAAb3hfAJZgvg_tU8EG0GZdVfIGY7ZKmNY4E9lclUvWO"));
    BufferedImage sponsor = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.imgur.com/U1p05Ri.png"));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    JLabel sponsorlabel = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon sponsorlabelicon = new ImageIcon();
    sponsorlabel.setIcon(sponsorlabelicon);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    frame.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
    sponsorlabel.setBounds(1600, 900, 1600, 900);
    sponsorlabel.setLocation(0, size.height);
    sponsorlabel.setSize(1600, 900);
    Image dimg = sponsor.getScaledInstance(sponsorlabel.getWidth(), sponsorlabel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    sponsorlabelicon.setImage(dimg);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.add(sponsorlabel);
    frame.setSize(1600, 900);
    frame.setIconImage(img);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Any particular  reason you're using an undecorated window?

Comment: I think... for design?

Comment: *I think... for design?* - don't know what that means. By default a JFrame does have a titlebar and borders. This allows you to set a title for the frame, minimize the frame, drag the frame, resize the frame etc. The reason you use an undecorated frame is that you don't want all the above functionality. Also, don't use a null layout and setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You can't just randomly give a label a size. The image will be painted at its actual size.

Comment: Well, it certainly looks as if there is either no way at all or, at least, no _obvious_ way, to move undecorated windows.  You'll just have to decide if your design choice is worth that that little "side benefit".

Comment: If you still really need an undecorated frame then check out: [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). It will allow you to drag the frame (by dragging a panel contained in the frame).

Comment: @camickr, I have to put an image with jlabel to make background and 2 jtextarea and jlabel to make "Email" and "Password", what do you recommend to use as layout manager? It is the only way I have been able to use so far.

Comment: So you are making a "login" frame. I see no reason to use an undecorated frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can use one or more panels each with its own layout manager to achieve your desired layout. I can't suggest what to use since only you know what you final layout should look like. Note you can set a layout manager for the JLabel that you are using as a background and then add your components to the label.